# Selenium finds element but returns it not as it should

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm currently trying to use `Selenium` to automate some tedious tasks that involve searching for certain articles in a website, getting the results and storing them in a file.

My problem is, I'm doing this:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('text')
```

but a `Selenium.webbrowser` object is returning, not the link I need.

I've inspected the HTML code for the page, and it looks like

```
<a href = 'link.html'>text</a>
```

Just like the selenium `'doc'` says it's what `find_element_by_link_text` is designed to deal with.

My code is essentially the following:

```py
driver.get(base_url)
search_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('search-field')
search_box.send_keys('text i need to search', Keys.ENTER)
new_url = driver.find_element_by_link_text('text i need to find')
driver.get(new_url)
```

Like I mentioned, `new_url` is not a valid argument to the `get()` function, as it is an object.

Comment: I believe `.get_attribute("href")` on the element will return what you need.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnGordon, that did it. If Selenium had an acessible and detailed documentation (been looking for one the whole afternoon) this wouldn't have been a problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @AntônioGabrielZeniLandim I have posted the answer. According to OP comment and added some links to check and learn. You may mark that as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is according to John Gordon, you are trying to use this:

```
.get_attribute("href")
```

It will return link inside `href` from selected element. [Here's](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) the official documentation. Check there for more information. You may find other interesting option there.

You may learn a little bit about `.get_attribute()` from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get_attribute-element-method-selenium-python/) also.